# Перенос данных через gitHub

Tags: git

Я новичок в гит, но пытаюсь разобраться. Подскажите, как правильно переносить данные с одного удаленного репо в другой. Моделирую ситуацию, когда есть рабочий комп(firstMachine), сервер(secondMachine) и репо на gitHub (gitRepoTest). Опишу свои действия с комментариями, чтобы знающие люди поправили в нужных местах:

1. Создал репо в gitHub/gitRepoTest, создал в нем файл README.MD со сторокой "created in gitHub"
2. Перенес в первый локальный репо (папка firstMachine) код:

- **git init** инициализирую репо
- **git remote add sn https://github.com/user/repo.git** добавил удаленный репо и присвоил ему короткое имя "sn"
- **git fetch sn** добавил удаленный репозиторий
- **git checkout main** перешел в ветку main

4. Такми образом в локальном репо (firstMachine) у меня отобразился файл README.md Моя задача - создать ветку, работать в ней, отобразить изменения, созданные в данной ветке в репозитории на gitHub, а после этого перенести данные изменения на сервер (secondMachine):

- **git checkout -b level-1** создаю ветку level-1 и перехожу в нее

5. Делаю изменение в файле README.md - добавляю строку "new string in firstMachine" и сохраняю изменения:

- **git add README.md**
- **git commit -m "created commit in firstMachine"**

Тут начинаются проблемы...
Далее мне нужно решить две задачи:

1. Чтобы ветка level-1 отобразилась в gitHub/gitRepoTest c изменениями, которые я зафиксировал. Я сумел выполнить это командой:

- **git push -u https://github.com/user/gitRepoTest.git level-1** в итоге ветка level-1 отобразилась в gitHub.

**2. Вторая задача - мне нужно правильно отправить изменения из gitHub/gitRepoTest на secondMachine**.
При этом дальнейшее взаимодействие такое - я что-то правлю на firstMachine, отправляю в gitHub и оттуда на secondMachine. Вот с этим пока загвоздка

Comment: Вроде бы у вас прощено самое важное - push вашей локальной ветки на GitHub. Ну и лишние действия при получении копии кода на компе - достаточно просто `git clone ТУТ_URL_РЕПОЗИТОРИЯ` сделать. После этого вам надо либо мержить ветки либо checkout нужной ветки на нужном компе делать.

Comment: "Чтобы ветка level-1 отобразилась в gitHub/gitRepoTest c изменениями, которые я зафиксировал. Я сумел выполнить это командой" - пропишите один раз remote в обоих локальных репозиториях, и дальше делайте просто "git push" после коммита. Ветку указывать тоже не нужно, если вы уже находитесь в ней. Чтобы запушенные изменения появились на другом компе, делайте "git pull" (находясь в той же ветке)

Comment: @insolor спасибо! Ура!!! спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

1. Первый пункт без изменений
2. Просто клонируете репозиторий, для этого на обоих компах выполняете: `git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git`. Дополнительно прописывать remote, делать checkout на главную ветку после этого не нужно, это происходит автоматически при клонировании
3. Делаете изменения как вы описали (создание ветки, редактирование, `git add ...`, `git commit`), потом отправляете изменения в репозиторий на github командой `git push` без всяких дополнительных параметров (если вы уже находитесь в нужной ветке, то ее имя при пуше указывать не нужно). Если ветка с таким именем еще не пушилась, нужно выполнить команду `git push -u origin имя_ветки`.
4. На втором компе делаете `git pull` (подтянутся изменения той ветки, в которой вы находитесь) или `git pull origin имя_ветки` - если ветки в репозитории на этом компе еще нет. Вместо origin пишите название вашего remote, если он у вас назван как-то по-другому (например, у вас в вопросе это sn).

Comment: Делал все по вашей инструкции. На этапе git push (где "потом отправляете изменения в репозиторий на github командой git push без всяких дополнительных параметров"), получил ошибку:
$ git push
fatal: The current branch level-1 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin level-1

Comment: собственно все-таки у меня потребовалось добавление  git push -u origin level-1

Comment: Да, забыл про эту деталь. Дополнил.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, не уверен, что это верно по кол-ву кода, но это сработало...
на secondMachine я так же инициализировал репо, добавил удаленный репо, в котором уже была ветка level-1. Далее я перешел в эту ветку:

```
$ git init  
$ git remote add serv https://github.com/user/gitRepoTest.git  
$ git fetch serv  
$ git checkout level-1
```

Вобщем - все. На secondMachine отобразились изменения, сделанные на firstMachine.
Теперь любые изменения на firstMachine сохраняются и пушатся git push в ветку level-1, а на secondMachine их так же легко забрать git pull

Comment: Первые три команды можно сократить до `git clone https://github.com/user/gitRepoTest.git`.